# как сделать дискорд бота с радио?

Tags: python, discord.py

Когда искал решение наткнулся на [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757011/how-to-create-a-discord-bot-that-streams-online-radio-in-python). Однако прога не работает. Я пробовал как в оригинале, так и чуть изменённый вариант:

```
import os

import discord
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

import settings_discord_bot as settings

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings.bot_prefix)
bot.remove_command('help')

#присоединиться
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, url: str = settings.music_url):
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)

    global player
    try:
        player = await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f'Я подключился к: {channel}')
    except:
        pass
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(settings.music_url))

#отключение от гс канала
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    #try:
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'Я отключился от: {channel}')
    #except AttributeError:
    pass

bot.run(settings.bot_token)
```

В обоих вариантах возникает ошибка `ClientException: ffmpeg was not found`
Если не сложно, скажите где моя ошибка, пожалуйста

Comment: "ClientException: ffmpeg was not found" И что тут не понятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске трансляции музыки ты должен передавать в аргументы FFmpegPCMAudio: executable(эксешник ffmpeg, который можно скачать на офф [сайте](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)) и непосредственно уже обработанную ссылку для трансляции - source.

```
player.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source=url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

Комманда должна выглядеть примерно так.